# Implement a return function

Tags: scheme, continuations, callcc

I'm trying to implement a `return` function in Scheme R6RS. I want something such that:

```
(lambda ()
  (do-some-job-before)
  (return some-value)
  (do-some-job-after))
```

executes `(do-some-job-before)`, do not execute  `(do-some-job-after)` and the final value of the lambda function in `some-value`.

I guess I have to use a continuation. I tried:

```
(define return #f)
(call/cc (lambda (k)
           (set! return k)))
```

but it does not work; e.g

```
(+ 2 (return 3)) ; -> 3 (and not 5 as I expected)
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 5):

**Edited:** Misread question.

Very easy in fact :)

```
(call/cc 
  (lambda (return)
    (printf "before\n")
    (return 3)
    (printf "after\n")))
```

Example [here](http://eval.ironscheme.net/?id=66).

**Note:** You cannot generalize this, except if you wrap it in syntax from an unhygienic macro.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not what I need. I DO NOT want that the clean-up part is executed.

Comment: @Aslan986: Just skip the dynamic-wind bit then, sorry I misread your question :) Editing answer.

Comment: @Aslan986: Your example does not really make sense why you would want this.

Comment: @Ieppie: I would like to do something like this: http://eval.ironscheme.net/?id=67 . (I know I can easly do this with a closure). I need a C-style `return` function.

Comment: @Aslan986: Unfortunately IronScheme does not have full blown continuations, so I can't really test it or suggest a working example unless I go to some other Scheme. I assume you want something like an infinite generator akin to `yield` in some languages. As you said, doing it with a closure is the normal way, and is the one I would use.